# Prolog: How do you iterate between two lists (nest for-loop)?

Tags: list, prolog

I just started learning Prolog this week so I am not sure if for-loops are possible in Prolog. 
I have two lists in Prolog

```
stringList([hi,hello],[bye,later],X).
```

How do I create a new solution list with one element per list?

So the output should be:

```
X = [hi,bye]
X = [hi,later]
X = [hello,bye]
X = [hello,later]
```

Comment: Some Prolog extensions allow "for"-loops, but for loops in itself are very "un-declarative". In declarative systems, you typically should think *what* should be done, not *how* it should be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A major advantage when using Prolog is that you can *delegate* such loops to the Prolog **engine**. You do not have to write them explicitly.

For example, in your case, think about the problem in this way: *What **holds** (or should hold) about `X`?*

We can say:

1. `X` is a list with two elements, say `[A,B]`.
2. `A` is a member of the list that is denoted by the first argument.
3. `B` is a member of the list that is denoted by the second argument.

So, in Prolog:

```
one_from_each(As, Bs, [A,B]) :-
    member(A, As),
    member(B, Bs).
```

Sample query:

```
?- one_from_each([hi,hello],[bye,later], X).
X = [hi, bye] ;
X = [hi, later] ;
X = [hello, bye] ;
X = [hello, later].
```

**And it works in other directions too**:

```
?- one_from_each(As, Bs, [hi,bye]).
As = [hi|_4656],
Bs = [bye|_4662] ;
As = [hi|_4656],
Bs = [_4660, bye|_4668] ;
As = [hi|_4656],
Bs = [_4660, _4666, bye|_4674] .
```

Hence, the whole question is somewhat misguided. When coding in Prolog, always ask: How can I formulate what ought to *hold*? Once you have such a formulation, you can leave the search for solutions to the Prolog engine!

If you *want*, you can be more explicit. For example:

```
one_from_each([], _) --> [].
one_from_each([L|Ls], Rs) -->
    one_from_each_(Rs, L),
    one_from_each(Ls, Rs).

one_from_each_([], _) --> [].
one_from_each_([R|Rs], L) -->
    [[L,R]],
    one_from_each_(Rs, L).
```

Example:

```
?- phrase(one_from_each([hi,hello],[bye,later]), Ls).
Ls = [[hi, bye], [hi, later], [hello, bye], [hello, later]].
```

This is sometimes called a **spatial** representation, because the solutions are now no longer found on backtracking (temporal representation), but represented explicitly.

From this, you see that "loops" correspond to *recursive* definitions.

Comment: Thanks! Follow up question: is there an easy way to delete a the sublist from the original list. For example if X = [hi, later]. How do I take it out of the list so my next answer is X = [hello,bye]? This is more of an issue when my list gets huge.

Comment: I think this is well worth its own question! Please file a separate question to discuss it.

Comment: Ok. I added the question. I think it requires recursion but that is an area that I am not really good at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52769929/prolog-how-do-i-delete-a-sublist-from-a-list-follow-up-question